# sql how to query all date in a given month (let's say April) of ANY year?

Tags: sql

How do I query all dates in April, for example, in any year?
If a table has data for multiple year, how do I get that?

```
where date between like '%-04-01' and like '%-04-30'
```

Tried the above code, obv it didn't work.

Comment: There are so many examples on the web. No research involved from your side... :(

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Does it have a function to extract the month from a date?

Comment: By usin g to_char() ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(date) = 4
```